# Debugging Qt program with Microsoft Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, qt, debugging, qt-creator

I created a complex program based on different modules which load after program has started. The program structure is very similar to QtCreator. Frankly speaking I've taken part of code from QtCreator. (plugin management system)
I'm trying to debug my program with Visual Studio 2013. Very often the debugger doesn't show correct values and skip lines of code or jump from a following line of code to the previous line. It seems to me that pdb file doesn't correspond to the proper file. How is that may be possible? Should I set specific or additional parameters for debugging Qt programs in MSVS 2013? What might be the reason of such behaviour of debugger?

ps. I installed Qt 5.4.1 for Windows 32-bit (VS 2013, 705 MB) along with Visual Studio Add-in 1.2.4 for Qt5 (156 MB) properly. 
I've made cleanup and rebuild several times, tried to delete related files after compilation - it didn't help.

Comment: 1. You use compile-time optimization. 2. Debug information for your plugins is not relevant.

Comment: What is compile-time optimization? I didn't setup anything specific for project settings except paths to my source code. Debug information for my plugins is relevant. I rebuilt it.

Comment: Ah, found a setting in C/C++ Code Generation. Set it to "Disabled" and it helped! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Go to project property pages-> C/C++ ->Optimization. Set 'Optimization' property to 'Disabled(/Od)'.

Thanks to  SaZ!